# Running .dmg app after building with Electron-Builder leads to "App quit unexpectedly."

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, dmg

Building the .dmg works and running the .dmg installer works. When I open the installed app, the app's icon appears in the Mac tool bar for a second and then disappears. An error window then appears that says "App quit unexpectedly."

The app installs and functions perfectly on Windows machines with .exe that Electron-builder had built. I am confused as to how the .dmg is not functioning and working the same way. Is my package.json missing something or incorrect?

I have also attempted to build a .pkg, but the same error occurs.

How I build the file:

1. Run react-scripts build
2. Run electron-builder

My pacakge.json:

```
{
  "name": "data-entry",
  "packageName": "Data Entry App",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "An app to quickly enter survey data.",
  "private": true,
  "author": "xxx",
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "src/start.js",
  "productName": "Data Entry App",
  "nsis": {
    "createDesktopShortcut": "always",
    "oneClick": false,
    "perMachine": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "xxx"
  },
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "app/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "appId": "com.myapp.DataEntry",
    "publish": {
      "provider": "github",
      "repo": "xxx",
      "owner": "xxx"
    },
    "npmRebuild": false,
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.41",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-json-storage": "^4.1.8",
    "electron-log": "^4.0.6",
    "electron-store": "^5.1.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.2.0",
    "firebase": "^7.8.1",
    "grpc": "^1.23.3",
    "http2": "^3.3.7",
    "node": "^10.9.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.12.0",
    "notistack": "^0.9.7",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-with-firebase-auth": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "react-build": "react-scripts build",
    "dist-all": "electron-builder"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^7.1.8",
    "electron-builder": "^20.44.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you've ever used this project at Windows to package then you should reinstall the node modules at mac. Hence, the electron modules for windows and mac is different

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have packaged with Windows before packaging with Mac. I have never deleted node_modules before doing npm install while on a Mac, only running npm install. So, I'll give that a go.

Comment: Update: This did not work, I am still receiving "App quit unexpectedly." I move the app into applications and attempt to open it and the error occurs.

Comment: I think you are packaging the node_modules too. This is not right way

Comment: Btw I can't sure why this app is closed unexpectedly. Try use it again

Comment: `rm -rf package-lock.json` `rm -rf node_modules` `npm install`